# How to delete already imported gpg public keys

Tags: linux

For example:
I have already deleted my public and private keys from the keyring...

The following line shows ID's associated with public keys already imported to GPG Database:

```
rpm -q gpg-pubkey --qf '%{name}-%{version}-%{release} --> %{summary}\n'

gpg-pubkey-db42a60e-37ea5438 --> gpg(Red Hat, Inc <security@redhat.com>)
gpg-pubkey-4f2a6fd2-3f9d9d3b --> gpg(Fedora Project <fedora@redhat.com>)
gpg-pubkey-23a254d4-41ddbc46 --> gpg(Jordi Rubalcaba <jrubalcaba@fedoranews.org>)
gpg-pubkey-23afgth6-78da6fd2 --> gpg(Jordi Rubalcaba <jrubalcaba@fedoranews.org>)
[jrubalcaba-fc3 ~]$
```

I want to delete the last 2 bottom lines so when I execute the command again ot does not show them.... Does any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per `man rpmkeys`:

> Finally, public keys can be erased after importing just like packages.  Here's how to remove the Red Hat GPG/DSA key
>
> ```
>   rpm -e gpg-pubkey-db42a60e
> ```

In your specific case:

```
rpm -e gpg-pubkey-23a254d4-41ddbc46 gpg-pubkey-23afgth6-78da6fd2
```

does what you want.